# Rails and ASP.NET Single Sign-On

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have an ASP.NET app which uses forms auth, and stores the credentials in a table - pretty vanilla. Since I know how the password is hashed, can I somehow share the forms auth cookie with Rails, effectively creating a single sign-on? Both web apps will live in the same domain.

Answer (score 7):

You can share the ASP.NET Forms Auth Cookie with Rails, but you'll have to decrypt it on the Rails side. Maybe it's too much trouble.

A simpler solution is to skip .NET Forms Authentication Ticket and persist **your own auth ticket (cookie)** on both sides, using the encryption algorithm you want and the same salt among the two platforms. The salt can be saved on the database or a physical file, if they reside on the same disk.

An example:

C# side:

```
public class MyTicket {
  ...
  public string ToSerializableFormat() {
    return String.Format("{0}|{1}", t.Username, t.somethingElseYouNeed);
  }

  public static MyTicket Parse(string value) {
    var vals = value.Split('|');
    return MyTicket(values[0], values[1]);
  }
}
```

Somewhere else in your application, replacing the `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt` and `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt` calls:

```
string MakeTicket(MyTicket t) {
  return EncryptSomehow(key, t.ToSerializableFormat());
}

MyTicket ReadTicket(string cookieValue) {
  return MyTicket.Parse( DecryptSomehow(key, cookieValue) );
}
```

And the Ruby-equivalent would be:

```
class MyTicket
  def to_serializable_format
    "#{@username}|#{@something_else}"
  end

  def self.parse(value)
    values = value.split '|'
    MyTicket.new(*values)
  end
end
```

Somewhere in your Rails code you'll decrypt and encrypt the auth cookie. Use the same name on both sides.

Profit.

Comment: I'd be under the impression that it's more work than it's worth as well. This is the kind of solution I would focus on instead.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm getting at. I have the password hashing algorithm implemented in both C# and Ruby. How would I decrypt the ASP.NET forms auth cookie in Rails though? I need to avoid having the user to log in twice - hence "single" sign-on ;-)

Comment: You can try to run Reflector ( http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/ ) on `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt` to see how .NET does it. But my suggestion is to skip the Forms Auth Ticket at all, and write your own "ticket" that you know how to decrypt on both sides. I edited the response to make it clear.

Comment: Part of the forms auth ticket involves signing with the ASP.NET machine key. Unless you specifically set it in web.config it changes ever time the app pool regenerates - something that may just be too much effort for you to do. However if you roll your own you will want to sign as well as encrypt, otherwise, well, you're in a world of pain.

Comment: I have the machine key set in web.config. How can I write my own ticket using this key so that I can also decrypt on the rails side? Is it just a matter of matching the :cookie_store, :key => '...' and secret_token values?

Comment: @Mark - No, you'll have to build your own data structure, serialization and deserialization on both ends. I'll update the answer with some sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sharing the auth cookie -- that would probably be difficult. But sharing the identity information would be pretty simple.

I would write a user model in Rails that acts as an adapter to your existing identity table, using the `establish_connection` trick:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(
    { :adapter => "mysql", 
      :database => "db_name", 
      :host => "db.example.com",
      :username => "user",
      :password => "password" })
end
```

this will make the User model connect to a different db. Event better, you could add another entry in `database.yml` and load it here.

Then, you would simply need to overload the accessor functions to deal with the non-standard schema.